# Blender explosion animation not rendering

Tags: animation, particles, fire

I am trying to create an explosion in Blender. However, when I try to render the explosion, this white box gets bigger in my particle domain but I can see the explosion in the viewport. What am I missing?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Found out that I just needed to put on a material for my domain. Now there is no box. But when rendering there is no explosion either. 1 frame just renders for like 10 minutes and there is no explosion. Guess I'll have to try to make my explosion from scratch.